# Fresh install 20.10 stops on EFI shell 2.3.1 startup.nsh

Tags: boot, uefi, 20.10

Sorry, I searched here and googled a lot but seems all answers are Virtualbox or not the same issue.

Computer that has had Ubuntus etc before, fresh install of 20.10, no virtual layer, just install from scratch. No dual boot, just the one vanilla Ubuntu OS overwriting the whole drive.

Everytime I boot now I end up in some EFI shell, version 2.3.1 and it mentions startup.nsh. Never seen anything like it.

Figured out after a while that I can just type "exit" and it will boot normally, so that's not the biggest problem in the world, but:

- what has happened here?
- and can I fix it?

Everything on the internet seems to mention Virtualbox, but that's not the case here, or any other virtualization. Thanks!

Comment: Check your BIOS and see if the EFI Shell seems to be the default boot.  From Intel it appears to be booting to the EFI Shell:  https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/motherboards/server/sb/efi_instructions.pdf

Comment: Hmm thanks, will check a bit later - I have not changed any BIOS settings ever, so I am a bit confused why it started doing this now. I was rummaging a little bit in BIOS after this happened, but I guess I will have to dig deeper.